# iOS: Prompting the user to make a phone call

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a view that, when clicked, should prompt the user to make a phone call. I am attempting to use the code below:

```
     NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:locPhone];
    NSString *phoneString = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    phoneString= [phoneString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    phoneString= [phoneString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    phoneString= [phoneString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneString]];
```

I know that the code is reached, and that the ultimate value of "phoneString" is a 10 digit phone number. There is no error, but nothing happens. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I see now that canOpenURL returns NO. Is this because I'm running this on the simulator?

Comment: how did you know that the code is reached?

Comment: it seems to me like that should work, without issues, if you debug are you sure it gets to those lines?

Comment: You should always use `canOpenURL` first. Does it return YES?

Comment: can u log the final phoneString and show us... & u can also do one more thing, just for testing directly give a number with all the formats u want to try, and implement which worked or u liked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but note that the simulator cannot simulate phone calls (testing it with `canOpenURL` on the simulator will return `NO`).

You should test your code on an actual device, you will probably see that it works as expected.

By the way, you really should add the `canOpenURL` test in your application, and display some alert to the user in that case, because users may run your application on an iPod device for example or on iPad, and neither can perform phone calls.